# Cassandra Timeout with COUNT query

Tags: macos, cassandra, homebrew

> NOTE: I am having more than 15967908 records. I am a newbie to
>   Cassandra. Reference: [Is there a way to effectively count rows of a very huge partition in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744943/is-there-a-way-to-effectively-count-rows-of-a-very-huge-partition-in-cassandra)
>
> [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes in Cassandra Datastax while insert data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575125/coordinator-node-timed-out-waiting-for-replica-nodes-in-cassandra-datastax-while)

Hi pals, I search for other answers but it didn't work out for me. They had mentioned that we need to increase the time out in **cassandra.yaml** file but the problem is I don't have the file.

I have installed the Cassandra with HomeBrew. Following is the version that I am currently running on my MacBook

```
cqlsh:cassandra_training> show version;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

When I do

```
cqlsh:cassandra_training> select count(*) from access_point_logs;
```

Then getting the following error

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 1 responses." info={'received_responses': 1, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Which file I need to increase the timeout. As I am not getting the **cassandra.yaml** file.

My Cassandra installation path is as follows

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.4
```

Is there any way to count the number of records.

Comment: Which Cassandra are you using DSE or OSS?

Comment: @Nama I am using an open source from apache website as Datastax are not supporting new versions and we need to upgrade to enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the issue. While creating the table I was not properly adding the **Primary Key** with **Cluster Key** because of which it was showing this kind of error.

Earlier I had created a table structure in the following way

```
create table access_point_logs (
    id bigint primary key,
    wd_number varchar,
    ip_address varchar,
    mac_address varchar,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    access_point_id bigint
);
```

Now changed it to the following

```
create table access_point_logs(
    id bigint,
    wd_number varchar,
    ip_address varchar,
    mac_address varchar,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    access_point_id bigint,
    primary key ((wd_number), created_at, mac_address)
) with clustering order by (created_at desc);
```

Just in case if any newbie like me I would like to add the following definition and examples to understand what Partition Key and what Cluster Key is

Carefully observe the change with the following

```
primary key ((wd_number), created_at, mac_address);


Partition Key - wd_number

Cluster Key - created_at, mac_address
```

> Partition Key - Which particular node to store the data in the
>   Cluster.
>
> Clustering Key - Mainly used for sorting the data and how to display
>   default order while fetching the data.
>
> Primary Key - Maybe a combination of Partition Key + Cluster Key or
>   just a Partition Key

Hope it may help someone. In case if anyone has queries please feel free to fire. I will do my best to answer those.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is no. You shouldn't be running queries without specifying any keys as it is not how Cassandra was designed.

If you just need a one off number, you can use [nodetool tablestats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablestats.html) to do so.

```
nodetool tablestats cassandra_training.access_point_logs
```

Look for "Number of keys (estimate)" in the output.

The above command will give you an estimated number of *partition keys* in your table, so this may or may not be what you are looking for.

If you need to get this number on a regular basis I would normally create another table of counters and manage it when you add/remove records from another table.

Comment: Invalid syntax at **|** in  nodetool tablestats cassandra_training access_point_logs | grep "Number of keys"

Comment: No bro still the same

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari Then remove the pipe and everything after it.  You should see a line stating "Number of partitions" which will give you an estimate on the number of partition keys present in the table's data.

Comment: Updated answer to remove the grep.

Comment: @JimWright Thank you very much for the support and helping me out.